# Javascript - What is happening to the callbacks in async parallel in this example?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I'm trying to teach myself javascript, and I am working my way through Mozilla's Express tutorial, and I came across this piece of code that is confusing me.

Each function in the object that is being passed as the first argument in async.parallel is being passed a callback argument. I'm learning about callbacks and how they work. Normally when I see a callback, it's invoked later on in the function that it's passed into something like callback(), or callback(null, result), but I don't see that here. Any idea why that's the case?

Just as a heads up, the count method (from the Mongoose api) accepts two arguments, the second one being a callback.

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {

    async.parallel({
    book_count: function(callback) {
        Book.count(callback);
    },
    book_instance_count: function(callback) {
        BookInstance.count(callback);
    },
    book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
        BookInstance.count({status:'Available'},callback);
    },
    author_count: function(callback) {
        Author.count(callback);
    },
    genre_count: function(callback) {
        Genre.count(callback);
    },
}, function(err, results) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, you can read up on [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel).

The reason you don't see `callback(null, result)`, is because the callback is being directly passed to mongoose. It is important to note, that it is mongoose that is invoking the callback function - not your code.

For example:

```
book_count: function(callback) {
    Book.count(callback);
},
```

Is the same as writing

```
book_count: function(callback) {
    Book.count(function(error, result) { 
        callback(error, result);
    });
},
```

As you can see, the second example only adds a "wrapper"-function - which is not really needed. It is much more readable to just pass along the callback to mongoose (which has the same convention of accepting error as the first argument, and result as the second).